# How to compute the "Total Adjustment Requested" when filing a dispute following a tax audit from Massachusetts?

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, massachusetts, audit, dispute

I got audited by the state of Massachusetts, USA, due to a mistake I did when filing my 2015 Form 1 (mirror). The audit's conclusion was that I have to pay 1000 USD to Massachusetts, and in addition 150 USD for interest. I am filing a dispute, where I claim that Massachusetts owes me 50 USD.

What should I write in the "Total Adjustment Requested"?

Should it be:

- 1000 + 50 = 1050 USD
- -(1000 + 50) = -1050 USD
- 1000 + 150 + 50 = 1200 USD
- -(1000 + 150 + 50) = -1200 USD
- something else?

---

Screenshot of the form from https://mass.gov/masstaxconnect:

[image]

Comment: There’s not enough information in your post to answer your question for anyone outside of the tax agency you’re filling the form out for. The link doesn’t work and you’ve given very little information about what steps you’ve tried to find the answer you need. There are some help options on their website including an FAQ about disputes or contacting them. Without a lot more information I don’t see how we can help.

Comment: @T.M. what information is missing to answer the question? Also, there are many taxpayers in Massachusetts